# How do I select variables in an array (A) with values from a variable (B)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm developing a video game using JavaScript and html Canvas and I'm trying to make it so that depending on what value:

```
PlayerIcon = 0;
```

is, the computer will draw that specific number from an array:

```
PlayerI = [];
PlayerI[0] = new Sprite("");
PlayerI[1] = new Sprite("");
PlayerI[2] = new Sprite("");
```

I don't exactly understand how undefined values work
(eg .this [i])
But it should be possible with them right? I already know how to do this in JavaScript however I would like to be able to make this into only a few lines of coding (no matter how many variables I add to the array):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var timer = setInterval(gameLoop,10);
var PlayerIcon = 0;
var PlayerI = [];

function gameLoop()
{
if(PlayerIcon == 0)
{
PlayerI[0].draw(ctx);
}
if(PlayerIcon == 1)
{
PlayerI[1].draw(ctx);
}
if(PlayerIcon == 2)
{
PlayerI[2].draw(ctx);
}
}
```

then I will assign a picture to each PlayerI variable and switch which one is being displayed with the PlayerIcon variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PlayerI[PlayerIcon].draw(ctx);` should do the trick

Comment: Wait really? I didn't know it's that easy!

Comment: I just tried it and it worked! Thanks a ton! (I kinda feel bad posting this question now because it was so easy XP)

Comment: Don't worry, we all had to learn and figure out at some point. Good luck with your game

Comment: True. Thank You!